# Cant get JSON POST data submitted via Slim

Tags: php, post, slim

Im using Postman (in Chrome) to test Slim calls but cant figure out how to get any of the posted JSON data.

Im submitting raw JSON:

```
{"name":"John Smith", "age":"30", "gender":"male"}
```

With Content-Type: application/json in the header

via POST to:

```
http://domain/api/v1/users/post/test/
```

Every attempt to get the JSON data gives a fatal error (see code comments below)

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\ContentTypes());


$app->group('/api/v1', function () use ($app) {

    $app->group('/users/post', function () use ($app) {

        $app->post('/test/', function () {

                print_r($app->request->headers); //no errors, but no output?

                echo "Hello!"; // outputs just fine

        $data = $app->request()->params('name'); //Fatal error: Call to a member function request() on a non-object
                $data = $app->request->getBody(); //Fatal error: Call to a member function getBody() on a non-object
                $data = $app->request->post('name'); //Fatal error: Call to a member function post() on a non-object
                $data = $app->request()->post(); //Fatal error: Call to a member function request() on a non-object

                print_r($data);
                echo $data;

        });

    });

});

$app->run();
?>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `var_dump($app)` where the first Fatal error appears. Maybe try using $this instead of $app.

Comment: var_dump($app) results in a NULL

Comment: $this->request()->getBody(); = Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure to curry `$app` into the last nested route, like so:

```
// Pass through $app
$app->post('/test/', function () use ($app) {
```

You're doing it everywhere else, so I'm assuming you just overlooked it.

Comment: Thanks, but the Slim docs only have "use ($app)" in the groups and not the actual routes: http://docs.slimframework.com/#Route-Groups

Comment: That's because the examples don't use `$app` in those routes.  You only curry what you actually need.  We're talking about a PHP language requirement here, not a Slim requirement: "Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the use language construct." http://us1.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: It works! Thanks! But, geez. This is probably the 10th issue I ran in to because the docs have inaccurate code/info.

Comment: @Ahhk: Poor documentation can be very frustrating, but in this case the author assumed some knowledge of PHP's anonymous functions.  In the other 9 cases, it would be awesome, if you have the time and inclination, if you'd open an issue against the documentation repo: https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Documentation/issues

Comment: Im new to Slim/REST so I was just going by the examples and didnt really analyze it much. Another example: docs show code to add middleware as "$app->add(new Slim_Middleware_ContentTypes())". This doesnt work. It has to be as I have it above (after extensive searching and hair pulling). :)

Comment: Where do you see that in the docs, @Ahhk?  I can't find that anywhere.

Comment: On a side note, do I need to add the "use ($app)" on any routes that Im passing JSON data to? Otherwise, if all the data is define in the route...then I dont need it. Right?

Comment: 1. Be careful about using 2 year old blog posts as documentation. Check everything against docs.slimframework.com. 2. You need to `use ($app)` anywhere you need to have access to `$app` within an anonymous function. If you need to call `$app->something`, then you need to add `use ($app)`.

Comment: @Ahhk variable *scope* is something you should grasp here. `$app` doesn't have anything to do with passing JSON, etc., it's just a variable that you want to access within a function, and functions can't access variables outside of their scope unless they're passed in via `use()` or `global` keywords.

Answer (score 1):

you have to get the body from the request:

$app->request->getBody();

http://docs.slimframework.com/request/body/

Answer (score 1):

In Slim 3 I've used the value of body in curl POST data and it didn't work,
to fix this I've used this, the body is object not string:

```
$app->post('/proxy', function($request, $response) {
    $data = $request->getBody()->getContents();
    $response->getBody()->write(post('http://example.com', $data));
});
```

You can check more methods on body in [docs](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/request.html#the-request-body)

Answer (score 0):

```
    //You did not pass the ($app) in your post route... so make it correct 
    $app->post('/test/', function () use ($app){
        //now if you want to get json data so please try following code instead of print_r($app->request->headers);
        $us=$app->request->getbody(); 

        //$us will get the json data now if you want to decode it and and want to get an array so try following..
        $ar=json_decode($us,true);
        //now you have $ar array of json data use it where you want..
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$app->post('/test/', function () use ($app){
        instead of print_r($app->request->headers);
        $ar=$app->request->getbody(); 

       to get an array so try following..
        $arry=json_decode($ar,true);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems by default that Slim doesn't support receiving of JSON. You'd have to create a middleware class to be able to read it. You can find out more here: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/request.html#the-request-body

It will however always be able to read requests sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`